# Angular JS simple button ng-click doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

I have the following HTML

```
<html  ng-app="processBeautifierApp">
...
<body ng-controller="PBCtrl" style="padding: 20px;">
<div id="header">
    <div style="padding: 7px; float: right;">
        <select ng-model="selectedProcess" ng-options="prozess as prozess for prozess in prozessListe"></select><br/>
        <button type="button" ng-click="forceRefresh()">Force DCTM Refresh</button>
    </div>
</div>
...
</body>
```

The corresponding javascript

```
var processBeautifierApp = angular.module('processBeautifierApp', []);
processBeautifierApp.controller('PBCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $window){
   ...
   $scope.forceRefresh = function() {
      ...
   }
});
```

The `select` element and the button are showing correctly. The options have been populated from the mode, `$scope.selectedProcess` changes when the user selects a different option.

But: The `ng-click` of the button doesn't react. `$scope.forceRefresh()` will never be called. There is no error on the console ... it just doesn't react at all. Can you see why?

Comment: check all files included correctly

Comment: Create a plnker or fiddle for your prblem

Comment: Which files exactly? I can see that Angular JS has been included correctly because the `select` has been populated and its corresponding `$scope.$watch` is working fine. But `$scope.forceRefresh = function()` doesn't

Comment: did u try to add a `alert()` inside the function ?

Comment: Here's a working example http://plnkr.co/edit/jQWdvsDr9EFwEICzIewx?p=preview

Problem needs to lay elsewhere

Comment: @devnull69 Please share your plunker

Comment: R u sure no console error as I'm getting Error: Unknown provider: $intervalProvider <- $interval. If console error.. then the $interval service was added with version 1.2.0-rc.3 (See https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#120-rc3-ferocious-twitch-2013-10-14). This error will happen with any version before this.

Comment: Note: when I removed this  **$interval**, it really works like charm

Comment: Trying to set up a fiddle. But it doesn't seem to like my Angular JS specific attributes like `ng-app` or `ng-controller`. It is just ignoring them which leads to numerous errors ... can you help me with that also?

Comment: You can use this http://plnkr.co/edit/jQWdvsDr9EFwEICzIewx?p=preview and set up your code here

Comment: Hi i think there would be a minute error in your `forceRefresh` function... Please check it once..

Answer (score 0):

Check the working example of your code [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/JRhdOWFczidrz6F3kCMP?p=preview)

```
var processBeautifierApp = angular.module('processBeautifierApp', []);
processBeautifierApp.controller('PBCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $interval, $window){
  $scope.forceRefresh = function() {
    alert("asd");
}
});
```

Comment: I can see the working example. But it still doesn't work in my project, even though I reduced the code inside `forceRefresh` to `alert('clicked')`. Maybe it is related to the fact that I use `JointJS` and `UIkit` ... never had such a problem until now

Comment: There must be silly mistake in your code. Try to rewrite it again. Or show your code.

Comment: Also had this mad mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was as simple as possible ... I am really ashamed

I used `$scope.forceRefresh` as the name of the function, but I also used `$scope.forceRefresh` somewhere else in the code as a boolean flag to enable/disable force refresh. Renaming the function did the trick